# How to auto change page with vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

As the title suggests, there are two pages in the code. I want to show the page **HelloWorld** first then show next page **myPage** without any click.
(maybe 2 sec after..) How to auto change a page with `vue-router`?

I know should set some code in `setTimeout` function.

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import myPage from '@/components/myPage'



Vue.use(Router)


export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/myPage',
      name: 'myPage',
      component: myPage
    }
  ],

})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to transition from `HelloWorld` to `MyPage` component then use `created` or `mounted` hook of the **HelloWorld** component like this:

```
created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // You can also use replace() instead of push()
        this.$router.push('/myPage');
    }, 2000);
}
```

Read more about [hooks here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do that in your HelloWorld.vue file. You will have something like this in the **mount** function of your HelloWorld.vue file

```
mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.$router.push('/next-route')
    }, 2000)
}
```

Hope that helps